# math operator spacing when used with delimiter modifiers such as \left \right, \big \Big etc

Tags: spacing, best-practices, delimiters, maxima

I noticed that using any delimiter modifiers like `\left(` `\right)` or `\big(` `\Big(` *etc* after a math operator like `\cos` inserts a small horizontal space.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312474/extra-horizontal-space-when-using-big-and-big-instead-of-left-and-right) suggests that one simply not use these commands and use the `\bigl`, `\Bigl` *etc* alternatives; however, I was wondering what the recommended solution is when the argument is not known, in advance?

E.g. Maxima is an open-source computer algebra system that has the option of auto-generating tex output of the computations (similar to what Mathematica does, except it's free); however, the rules for generating tex output are set programmatically, for all output. As such, all powers of trigonometric functions would be rendered like `\cos^{n} \left( <arg> \right)` to ensure that the parentheses work with any argument.

**Is there any way to redefine `\left(` `\right` to remove this extra horizontal space? or would it be more appropriate to modify the output for each type of operator, individually?** e.g. use `\hspace` to delete space on an operator-by-operator case?

Apologies for the quasi-off-topic nature of the question: it seemed to me the TeX community was the more appropriate SE to go with, in this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{(}{)}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\cos \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \\
&\cos \mathopen{}\left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \\
&\cos\! \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \\
&{\cos} \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \\
&\cos \parens*{\frac{t}{2}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

(1) is the output you wanted to change, (2) is wipet’s excellent answer, (3) inserts a negative space, (4) changes the spacing of `\cos` from operator to ordinary (like `f(x)`, but will also mess up the spacing of expressions like `2 {\cos}^2`.) and (5) uses `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`.

I would recommend (5) as the template to use for automatic generation, if you can also generate the preamble.  If you need to be able to copy-and-paste the snippet into any document, go with (2).

The reason the default behavior is that way is that DEK was probably thinking of “math operators” like `\sum` and `\int` when he defined the spacing.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer and clear exposition! Really appreciate your taking the time to reply so thoughtfully. Normally I leave a few days for others to way in, but I can't imagine a more comprehensive response. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: I would reminder that (5) is LaTeX-only solution. The OP mentions TeX, no LaTeX.

Comment: Comment ot solution (2): If you don't re-set the math-inner to math-ord usind `{\left(...\right)}`, then you (sometimes) get bad spacing after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: @wipet Thanks for the comments. Where does the question say, no LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\cos^{n} \mathopen{}{\left( argument\right)}
```

but auto-generated output has one problem: it is unable to generate human friendly text. Human can write `\cos^2 x` or `\cos^2 (x+y)` but machine must geneate `\cos^{2} \mathopen{}{\left(x+y\right)}`. Unfortunately. TeX language for math formula was intended for humans, not for machines.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply & great solution. `\mathopen` was not something I was familiar with. There is no doubt that there are many challenges associated with figuring out how to automate machine-generated TeX, but it seems a worthwhile project. Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge!